# Best practice to store secret for generating JWTs in a NodeJS app

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, express-jwt

I am using JWTs for authenticating users on a SPA (NodeJS backend, Angular frontend). I have a function in my User model to generate a JWT when the user signs in:

```
// ./models/user.js - with Waterline as ORM

var Waterline = require('Waterline');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

// [...]

generateJWT: function() {
  // set expiration to 60 days
  var today = new Date();
  var exp = new Date(today);
  exp.setDate(today.getDate() + 60);

  return jwt.sign({
    _id: this.id,
    username: this.username,
    exp: parseInt(exp.getTime() / 1000),
  }, 'SECRET'); // TODO: Real secret
}

// [...]
```

This 'SECRET' shouldn't be hardcoded. And it should not be in the codebase or in my repo. So what is the best / most secure way to handle this? A config file in a shared folder that is symlinked when deploying? The database?

Comment: Store it as an environment variable.

Comment: @BidhanA Could you give an example?

Comment: It would look like this in your node code `process.env.MY_SECRET`.  You just have to be sure you have the environment variable set when you run the server.  i.e. `export MY_SECRET=secret` from your shell.

Comment: Yo can store it in file, just make sure you set right permissions. You can even encrypt the file with second secret :)